# Error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an error in my console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null at
>   Object.game.map.genererateBlocked (main.js:57) at Object.game.new
>   (start.js:17) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:56)

I do not know what causes this error.

// main.js

```
//****************************** Initialise les obstacles ******************************//


game.map.genererateBlocked = function (nb) {

  for (var i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    var x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10); //genere un nombre entre 1 et 10
    var y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);

    var blocked = document.querySelector(".square[data-x='" + x + "'][data-y='" + y + "']"); // on recupere la case

    if (blocked.getAttribute("type") === "") { // test si la case est vide
      blocked.setAttribute("type", "blocked"); // on defini le type a blocked
      blocked.classList.add("blocked"); // on attribue la classe blocked
    } else {
      i--; // si la case n'est pas vide on recommence l'iteration
    };
  }
}
```

// start.js

```
game.map.generateMap(); // on genere la carte
game.map.genererateBlocked(nbBlocked); // on genere les obstacles
game.map.generateWeapons(nbWeapon); // on genere les armes
game.players.generatePlayers(); // on genere les joueurs
```

// index.html

```
<button onclick="game.new();" id="newgame">Nouvelle Partie</button>
```

Comment: I believe it's because `blocked` is null, so try and console log it and check. You can also log `".square[data-x='" + x + "'][data-y='" + y + "']"` and see if it's filled as you expect. It could also be a good idea to show us your html

Comment: Your query selector seems to not be matching any element.

Comment: The only thing we can say is that your `document.querySelector` returns `null` which means that it can't find an element for the given selector. But we can't really answer your question without knowing how your `square` elements look like. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

it's good I found my answer, it was the number to be generated to set to 7

```
game.map.genererateBlocked = function (nb) {

  for (var i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    var x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7); 
    var y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7);

    var blocked = document.querySelector(".square[data-x='" + x + "'][data-y='" + y + "']"); // on recupere la case

    if (blocked.getAttribute("type") === "") { 
      blocked.setAttribute("type", "blocked"); 
      blocked.classList.add("blocked"); 
    } else {
      i--; 
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add check that the block is really found. Modify the line:

```
if (blocked.getAttribute("type") === "") { // test si la case est vide
```

to:

```
if (blocked && blocked.getAttribute("type") === "") { // test si la case est vide
```

Comment: Sure, that fixes the error. But now the script will execute the `else` branch. Is that really what is supposed to happen?

Comment: @Ivar, Tbh I'm not sure if it shall or shall not go into the else statement if it's not found, I don't believe so, but I would be a good solution in case it would be null. The best solution would be to figure out why it returns null.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I'm not sure I completely follow you. `null` is a falsy value so the if-statement will not be executed and so the `else` statement will be. I definitely agree that a good solution would be to figure out why the `querySelector` can't find the element. It is very likely that the script did not anticipate on not being able to find that element so simply taking the `else` branch doesn't seem like the right approach.

Comment: @Ivar I'm not sure about else clause. May be it is not necessary at all. I can't read Freach comments about what is going on. Just addressed the initial technical issue...